# How do I format large numbers(int) in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I have a balance sheet of a company with large number which,  I want to format into a small number, I have this number:

```
55888000000
```

which I need to convert into:

```
$55.88
```

I Have tried this:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format
```

Here is the output:

[image: output]

Comment: how does one infer that `55888000000` is `55.88`? What about cases that can be conflicting such as `500000000000`?

Comment: Don't add [pictures of code/data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) this way we cannot reproduce an answer for you. Try to add some example data.  I see you have your data alread loaded in Jupyter Notebook, use `print(df)` and copy & paste the output of that in your question.

Comment: More importantly, where are you getting `55888000000`? Can't you reduce the size of the integer (by dividing it) there?

Answer (score 0):

Given a dataframe called `df`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'co1': {'a':55888000000, 'b':3495000000},
                       'co2': {'a':33888000000, 'b':11495000000}})
>>> df
           co1          co2
a  55888000000  33888000000
b   3495000000  11495000000
```

We can apply a formatting function with `applymap`:

```
>>> df.applymap(lambda x: '$ {0:.2f}'.format(x/1e9))
       co1      co2
a  $ 55.89  $ 33.89
b   $ 3.50  $ 11.49
```

Basically I'm dividing by 1e9 by default and turning it into a string  with the `format` function.